# Why are some Motherboards used multi pairs of multi-chanel slots for RAMs?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I've searched my question in google but I've failed to find my answer,
My question is, Why are some certain type of MBs used multi-pairs of multi-chanel RAMs slots,
For example, there is a MB with four slots form RAM , two of them green and two of them orange.
And if I use a pair RAMs in green slots, Can I stick a single RAM in one of orange ones? In other word Can I stick 3 RAMs, a dual RAMs and a single RAM?

Comment: yes, but you'll lose benefit (speed) of dual channel mode unless both channels are populated identically ... i.e. use an even number of sticks (2 or 4 in the example case) ... and, I believe, each pair of RAM is identical ... in the case of 4 sticks, you'd want two matching pairs of RAM (they don't ALL have to be the same size) ... speed should be the same, otherwise you'd run at the lowest speed all sticks can handle

Comment: https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/mixing-dual-channel-memories-with-single-channel-memory.2226845/

Comment: As we know, every RAMs has 64-bit bus and a dual-chanel be 128-bit. So if I use two pairs of  chanels  it'd be 256-bit?
in other word in  my example if i use 2 pairs (4 RAMs) it'd work like four-chanel memory. Is it true?

Answer (score 0):

There can be no other answer than "try it and see", as this kind
of setup relies heavily upon the properties of the motherboard,
the memory controller and the RAM. The motherboard manual are
often lacking in specifying the exact effect of such a
configuration (or perhaps there is not one answer).

If you have three RAM sticks, then depending on your
system configuration, the type of RAM you're using,
and your motherboard, introducing the third stick of RAM could
disable the dual-channel RAM support for the first two sticks
of RAM.
So, while you will have more capacity, your overall performance
may suffer.

On the other hand, it's possible that some motherboards will
manage to run the matching sticks in dual-channel and the
third one in single-channel.

The final answer will then be : "It depends".